# Sidebar missing from Homepage

Tags: css, sidebar

The [home page](http://www.superlogical.net/) displays the sidebar below the rest of all the latest posts, leaving a vacant sidebar area for the majority of the (long) page.  The sidebar displays fine on any [single post](http://www.superlogical.net/art/photography/2011/07/beautiful-treescape-photography/).

My **index.php** and **single.php** are practically identical, apart from minor differences in the "next post", "previous post".

There are no widgets deployed in the theme sidebar, which is called sidebar1; there are no other sidebars.  All the elements of the sidebar are coded into sidebar.php, and there are no conditions to check which page is calling the sidebar, so it should (and is) displaying the same content on both the index page, and on individual posts, just in different locations.

Category pages display the sidebar in the correct location too.

I thought that there might be posts with `<br clear="all">` listed on the home page, which were pushing the sidebar down, but the only post which has this content is not on the home page any more, and it [displays](http://www.superlogical.net/computing/windows/2011/07/add-edit-with-to-right-click-menu/) the sidebar fine.

None of the individual posts contain content which is too wide - they all display fine as individual posts, and even when the content is too wide, it just displays underneath the sidebar, it doesn't push it downwards.

I use a caching plugin, but I have cleared the cache on the server and in my browser.

When I display the site in IE8, I receive an error:

```
Webpage error details
Message: 'ajaxurl' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 102
Code: 0
URI: http://www.superlogical.net/wp-includes/js/wp-lists.js?ver=20110521
```

but I receive the same error on individual posts and the sidebar displays fine in IE8.

I haven't made any template changes in the last 2-3 days I can think of, and it was displaying fine yesterday.

There is nothing in Google Chrome CSS element inspector indicating any CSS issues that I can see.

Any ideas about what is happening here?

Comment: have you checked the validation of your site: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.superlogical.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 ?  the errors might also be in one or more of the posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the JS error. On the home page, you're missing a closing div tag for `#content` and that is throwing the sidebar down below. You have other code errors, too: [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   superlogical.net  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.superlogical.net/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: Thanks.  The index.php has a closing tag for the content div.  Where else should I look?

Comment: If I replace index.php with single.php the problem remains, so the problem can't be in index.php (in the theme folder).

Comment: Also, the majority of those errors are saying "the div tag is not allowed here".  Why not?  The doctype is transitional, not strict.  The other main errors are in the Google +1 plugin.